# Do convolutional networks to predict RxNorm codes from ICD9 codes make sense?

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, convolution

I have been asked by the company to specifically use a convolutional neural network to predict the type of medication (RxNorm code) prescribed based on the diagnoses given (ICD9 codes).  I will be given a million prescriptions written by doctors.  Each prescription is independent of the next one.

So an example would be: `110, 670, 890, BB2344`
The first 3 items are ICD9 codes, the last one is the output, the RxNorm code.  There are a million of these.

Honestly the task seems nonsensical to me.  I do not have any idea regarding how to structure the inputs.

There is no inherent order to the diagnoses and no timestamps.

One diagnosis may make another diagnosis more likely; but there are plenty of examples where they are just independent.

The ICD9 coding system has hierarchical structure, such that a code of 110 and 120 (both infections) are both more closely related than say a code of 110 and 890. (an infection and a wound).

Basically, what should my input "image" look like? Or does a CNN not make sense at all for this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CNN require spatial (or temporal) correlation in inputs. There is no such thing here, so the short answer is **no, it makes no sense**. In general, given how simplistic is the data, I would actually expect some basic linear model (on one hot encoded data) / or even basic rule inductions to work well.

The only possible use of "cnn-like" structures is to exploit the graph nature through graph-CNNs. Since the hierarchical structure in the input can be considered a "spatial" correlation.

Comment: thank you, this is what I thought.  I just wasn't sure because of the fact that ICD9 codes are hierarchical, so there is some inherent structure but this fact seemed to be not applicable to CNNs.

Comment: You can consider Graph CNNs then, which are based on a similar idea to "regular" CNNs, and can work with graph-represented data (and a hierarchy is a tree).